# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAssoc() on a non-object

Tags: 7

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAssoc() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\drupal\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code on line 34

May I know why this error occurs? Using druapl 7

Comment: This occurs because some code you used in PHP Filter content is buggy. Disable PHP module and it will go away. Of course then you would need to rewrite everything you wrote as code in content, recreate it as custom modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use(access) a variable as an object, that variable is not an object. That variable may be an array.

Comment: The funny thing is, I didn't make any change on code.It was working fine. Now, how can I get rid of this issue? can't even login as drupal admin.

Comment: @Keerthi Update own question what information you want. As per this answer for the question that you ask.

Comment: My issue was, a working copy of the site in my system unexpectedly displayed this error message.Now I checked all the block contents in DB and as you said, it was accessing an object which does not exists. The object name changed somewhere. Thanks for the advice :)